# Release build crashlytics is not sending line number in crashreport?

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

While debug mode development I am getting proper line number of crash while in release build I am getting crash file name but with unknown source.

```
I have included
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-keep class com.crashlytics.android.**
```

I have added above lines in ProGuard.

Answer (score 23):

Try following lines, in addition to your ProGuard rules:

```
# Preserve annotations, line numbers, and source file names
-keepattributes *Annotation*,SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

Comment: useful explanation here: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html